# nix-shell --command `stack build` leads to libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, postgresql, haskell, nixos, stackage

i am trying to compile my small project (a yesod application with lambdacms) on nixos. However, after using cabal2nix (more precisely cabal2nix project-karma.cabal --sha256=0 --shell > shell.nix) , I am still missing a dependency wrt. postgresql it seems.

My shell.nix file looks like this:

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}, compiler ? "default" }:

let

 inherit (nixpkgs) pkgs;

 f = { mkDerivation, aeson, base, bytestring, classy-prelude
      , classy-prelude-conduit, classy-prelude-yesod, conduit, containers
      , data-default, directory, fast-logger, file-embed, filepath
      , hjsmin, hspec, http-conduit, lambdacms-core, monad-control
      , monad-logger, persistent, persistent-postgresql
      , persistent-template, random, resourcet, safe, shakespeare, stdenv
      , template-haskell, text, time, transformers, unordered-containers
      , uuid, vector, wai, wai-extra, wai-logger, warp, yaml, yesod
      , yesod-auth, yesod-core, yesod-form, yesod-static, yesod-test
      }:
      mkDerivation {
        pname = "karma";
        version = "0.0.0";
        sha256 = "0";
        isLibrary = true;
        isExecutable = true;
        libraryHaskellDepends = [
          aeson base bytestring classy-prelude classy-prelude-conduit
          classy-prelude-yesod conduit containers data-default directory
          fast-logger file-embed filepath hjsmin http-conduit lambdacms- core
          monad-control monad-logger persistent persistent-postgresql
          persistent-template random safe shakespeare template-haskell  text
          time unordered-containers uuid vector wai wai-extra wai-logger      warp
          yaml yesod yesod-auth yesod-core yesod-form yesod-static
          nixpkgs.zlib
          nixpkgs.postgresql
          nixpkgs.libpqxx
        ];
        libraryPkgconfigDepends = [ persistent-postgresql];
        executableHaskellDepends = [ base ];
        testHaskellDepends = [
          base classy-prelude classy-prelude-yesod hspec monad-logger
          persistent persistent-postgresql resourcet shakespeare     transformers
          yesod yesod-core yesod-test
        ];
        license = stdenv.lib.licenses.bsd3;
      };

  haskellPackages = if compiler == "default"
                       then pkgs.haskellPackages
                       else pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler};

  drv = haskellPackages.callPackage f {};

 in

  if pkgs.lib.inNixShell then drv.env else drv
```

The output is as follows:

```
markus@nixos ~/git/haskell/karma/karma (git)-[master] % nix-shell     --command `stack build`
postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1: configure
ReadArgs-1.2.2: download
postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1: build
ReadArgs-1.2.2: configure
ReadArgs-1.2.2: build
ReadArgs-1.2.2: install

--  While building package postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1 using:
      /run/user/1000/stack31042/postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/ build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /home/markus/git/haskell/karma/karma/.stack-work/logs/postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1.log

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /run/user/1000/stack31042/postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1/Setup.hs, /run/user/1000/stack31042/postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/setup/Main.o )
Linking /run/user/1000/stack31042/postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/setup/setup ...
Configuring postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1...
Building postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1...
Preprocessing library postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1...
LibPQ.hsc:213:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
compiling .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Database/PostgreSQL/LibPQ_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
command was: /nix/store/9fbfiij3ajnd3fs1zyc2qy0ispbszrr7-gcc-wrapper-4.9.3/bin/gcc -c .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Database/PostgreSQL/LibPQ_hsc_make.c -o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Database/PostgreSQL/LibPQ_hsc_make.o -fno-stack-protector -D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=710 -Dlinux_BUILD_OS=1 -Dx86_64_BUILD_ARCH=1 -Dlinux_HOST_OS=1 -Dx86_64_HOST_ARCH=1 -I/run/current-system/sw/include -Icbits -I.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/autogen -include .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/bytes_6elQVSg5cWdFrvRnfxTUrH/include -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/base_GDytRqRVSUX7zckgKqJjgw/include -I/nix/store/6ykqcjxr74l642kv9gf1ib8v9yjsgxr9-gmp-5.1.3/include -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS/include -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/include -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/include/
```

I assume not much is missing, so a pointer would be nice.
What is also weird, that is that "nix-shell" works but following that up with "stack exec yesod devel" tells me

```
Resolving dependencies... 
Configuring karma-0.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
classy-prelude >=0.10.2,
classy-prelude-conduit >=0.10.2,
classy-prelude-yesod >=0.10.2,
hjsmin ==0.1.*,
http-conduit ==2.1.*,
lambdacms-core >=0.3.0.2 && <0.4,
monad-logger ==0.3.*,
persistent >=2.0 && <2.3,
persistent-postgresql >=2.1.1 && <2.3,
persistent-template >=2.0 && <2.3,
uuid >=1.3,
wai-extra ==3.0.*,
warp >=3.0 && <3.2,
yesod >=1.4.1 && <1.5,
yesod-auth >=1.4.0 && <1.5,
yesod-core >=1.4.6 && <1.5,
yesod-form >=1.4.0 && <1.5,
yesod-static >=1.4.0.3 && <1.6
```

When using mysql instead, I am getting

```
pcre-light-0.4.0.4: configure
mysql-0.1.1.8: configure
mysql-0.1.1.8: build
Progress: 2/59
--  While building package mysql-0.1.1.8 using:
          /run/user/1000/stack12820/mysql-0.1.1.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-    linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/ build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /home/markus/git/haskell/karma/karma/.stack-work/logs/mysql-0.1.1.8.log

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /run/user/1000/stack12820/mysql-0.1.1.8/Setup.lhs, /run/user/1000/stack12820/mysql-0.1.1.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/setup/Main.o )
Linking /run/user/1000/stack12820/mysql-0.1.1.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/setup/setup ...
Configuring mysql-0.1.1.8...
Building mysql-0.1.1.8...
Preprocessing library mysql-0.1.1.8...
In file included from C.hsc:68:0:
include/mysql_signals.h:9:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
 #include "mysql.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
compiling .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Database/MySQL/Base/C_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
command was: /nix/store/9fbfiij3ajnd3fs1zyc2qy0ispbszrr7-gcc-wrapper-4.9.3/bin/gcc -c .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Database/MySQL/Base/C_hsc_make.c -o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Database/MySQL/Base/C_hsc_make.o -fno-stack-protector -D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=710 -Dlinux_BUILD_OS=1 -Dx86_64_BUILD_ARCH=1 -Dlinux_HOST_OS=1 -Dx86_64_HOST_ARCH=1 -I/nix/store/7ppa4k2drrvjk94rb60c1df9nvw0z696-mariadb-10.0.22-lib/include -I/nix/store/7ppa4k2drrvjk94rb60c1df9nvw0z696-mariadb-10.0.22-lib/include/.. -Iinclude -I.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/autogen -include .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/bytes_6elQVSg5cWdFrvRnfxTUrH/include -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/base_GDytRqRVSUX7zckgKqJjgw/include -I/nix/store/6ykqcjxr74l642kv9gf1ib8v9yjsgxr9-gmp-5.1.3/include -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS/include -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/include -I/nix/store/xphvly2zcd6jsc2xklz1zmmz4y0dh3ny-ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/include/


--  While building package pcre-light-0.4.0.4 using:
  /home/markus/.stack/setup-exe-cache/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.4.0-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/ configure --with-ghc=/run/current-system/sw/bin/ghc --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/markus/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/pkgdb/ --libdir=/home/markus/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/lib --bindir=/home/markus/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/bin --datadir=/home/markus/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/share --libexecdir=/home/markus/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/markus/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/etc --docdir=/home/markus/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/doc/pcre-light-0.4.0.4 --htmldir=/home/markus/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/doc/pcre-light-0.4.0.4 --haddockdir=/home/markus/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/doc/pcre-light-0.4.0.4 --dependency=base=base-4.8.1.0-4f7206fd964c629946bb89db72c80011 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.6.0-18c05887c1aaac7adb3350f6a4c6c8ed
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /home/markus/git/haskell/karma/karma/.stack-work/logs/pcre-light-0.4.0.4.log

Configuring pcre-light-0.4.0.4...
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.4.0-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.2: The program 'pkg-config'
version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not be found.
```

After adding pkgconfig to my global configuration, the build seems to get a little further ahead, so it seems that shell.nix is ignored somewhat.

(Sources for what I tried so far:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-stack/_ZBh01VP_fo)

Update: It seems like I overlooked this section of the manual
http://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#using-stack-together-with-nix
However, the first idea that came to mind 
(stack --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/c6qy7n5wdwl164lnzha7vpc3av9yhnga-postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1/lib build)
did not work yet, most likely I need to use 
--extra-include-dirs or try one of the variations. It seems weird that stack is still trying to build postgresql-libpq in the very same version, though.

Update2: Currently trying out "stack --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/1xf77x47d0m23nbda0azvkvj8w8y77c7-postgresql-9.4.5/lib --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/1xf77x47d0m23nbda0azvkvj8w8y77c7-postgresql-9.4.5/include build" which looks promising. Does not look like the nix-way, but still.

Update3: Still getting

```
<command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /home/markus    /.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-11-17/7.10.2/lib/x86_64-linux-  ghc-7.10.2/postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1-ABGs5p1J8FbEwi6uvHaiV6/libHSpostgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1-ABGs5p1J8FbEwi6uvHaiV6-ghc7.10.2.so 
(libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) stack   build  186.99s user 2.93s system 109% cpu 2:52.76 total
```

which is strange since libpq.so.5 is contained in /nix/store/1xf77x47d0m23nbda0azvkvj8w8y77c7-postgresql-9.4.5/lib.
An additional

```
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/nix/store/1xf77x47d0m23nbda0azvkvj8w8y77c7-postgresql-9.4.5/lib
```

does not help either.

Update4:
By the way, yesod devel does the same as stack exec yesod devel. My libraries are downloaded to /nix/store but they are not recognized.
Maybe I need to make "build-nix" work and yesod devel does not work here?

Just for completeness, here is stack.yaml

```
resolver: nightly-2015-11-17
#run stack setup otherwise!!

# Local packages, usually specified by relative directory name
packages:
- '.'

# Packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver (e.g.,    acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps: [lambdacms-core-0.3.0.2 , friendly-time-0.4, lists-0.4.2,     list-extras-0.4.1.4  ]


 # Override default flag values for local packages and extra-deps
flags:
  karma:
    library-only: false
    dev: false

# Extra package databases containing global packages
extra-package-dbs: []
```

Next weekend, I will check out 
https://pr06lefs.wordpress.com/2014/09/27/compiling-a-yesod-project-on-nixos/
and other search results.

Comment: Just gave nixos another shot and it seems that nix:
  enable: true
  packages: [zlib] (in stack.yaml, see 
https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2130) is also necessary in addition to stack --nix build and the extrac-include-dirs and extra-lib-dirs below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny, because I've just had a similar problem myself - solved it by adding these two lines to `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-include-dirs: [/nix/store/jrdvjvf0w9nclw7b4k0pdfkljw78ijgk-postgresql-9.4.5/include/]
extra-lib-dirs: [/nix/store/jrdvjvf0w9nclw7b4k0pdfkljw78ijgk-postgresql-9.4.5/lib/]
```

You may want to check first which `postgresql`'s path from the `/nix/store` you should use with `include/` and `lib/`:

```
nix-build --no-out-link "<nixpkgs>" -A postgresql
```

And BTW, why do you use `nix-shell` if you are going to use `stack` *and* you have `project-karma.cabal` available..? Have you considered [migrating your project](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE.html#existing-projects) with `stack init`..?

Comment: Hi, I have no means of checking it right now. I assume it is the missing slash at the end or something like that.

Comment: It could also be a conflict with what is stated in stack.yaml. I'll add it to the question for future visitors.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `stack` is trying to build `haskellPackages.postgresql-libpq` outside of the `nix` framework.

You probably don't want that to happen. Maybe try to add `postgresql-libpq` to `libraryHaskellDepends`?

Comment: If I do this, I am getting error: undefined variable ‘postgresql-libpq’ at /home/markus/git/haskell/karma/karma/shell.nix:35:11. Prefixing it with haskellPackages leads to no error when running "nix-shell", but "nix-shell --command `stack build` " still doesn't work, same error as in the question.

Comment: Undefined variable-bug was due to forgetting to add postgresql-libpq to the f = {...} expression. Otherwise, the same bug as above.

Comment: I don't use `stack` on `nixos` so am a bit out of my depth. You might want to try the #nixos IRC channel on freenode

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer nails part of the question: they *manually* add include/lib paths from the `postgresql` package, that is installed because you run the server.

That is not the best way to do things. Instead add the `postgresql` package to your shell. The way Nix shells work, they *already* add the paths for your shell.

> Historically, `nix-shell` was intended to support development and debugging of derivations. This is why they behave as *development shells*.
>
> The reason this particular case is slightly confusing is that most packages split the dev outputs from the service/binary outputs. Many nix packages split out the development outputs under `.dev` like `libxml2.dev` or `curl.dev`. Postgres doesn't make the distinction, but you still need the compiler flags injected in your shell.

Example of a `default.nix` that I made today (and I ran into the missing `libpq-fe.h` problem):

```hs
{pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}}:
pkgs.mkShell {
  # nativeBuildInputs is usually what you want -- tools you need to run
  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs.buildPackages; [
    ruby_3_3
    ruby_3_3.devdoc
    rubyfmt
    openssl.dev
    readline.dev
    libyaml.dev
    sqlite.dev
    libxml2.dev
    curl.dev
    libffi.dev
    #
    rbenv
    postgresql
  ];
}
```